# Off doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to show confirm dialog before form submit:

```
  $('body').on('submit', 'form[data-confirm-dialog-text]', (e) ->
    form = $(this)
    e.preventDefault()
      $.show_dialog(form.data('confirm-dialog-title'), form.data('confirm-dialog-text'), form.data('ok-text'), form.data('cancel-text'), (->
        form.off('submit').submit()
      ))
  )
```

On success I do the following: `form.off('submit').submit()`, but keep getting confirm dialog, which means that form is not inbound.

If I change `$('body').on('submit', 'form[data-confirm-dialog-text]'` to `$('form[data-confirm-dialog-text]').on('submit',`everything works fine. What is the difference and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: because the event is bound to the body, not the form....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is bind to `body` and you should use remove the event from `body`. So change,

```
form.off('submit').submit()
```

to

```
$('body').off('submit', 'form[data-confirm-dialog-text]');
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

From jQuery's [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) documentation:

> The `.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Calling `.off()` with no arguments removes all handlers attached to the elements. Specific event handlers can be removed on elements by providing combinations of event names, namespaces, selectors, or handler function names. **When multiple filtering arguments are given, all of the arguments provided must match for the event handler to be removed**.

It means you should use the same arguments to `.off()` as to `.on`. So, try to change:

```
form.off('submit').submit();
```

To:

```
$('body').off('submit', 'form[data-confirm-dialog-text]');
form.submit();
```